# MySQL Spacial Query where rows/locations have differing radius

Tags: mysql, database, geolocation, spatial

I have a MySQL table containing the columns:

- Lat
- Lng
- Radius

I want to be able to query a specific Lat and Lng and the query return all the rows where the radius overlaps that location.

I know how to query for locations in a given radius but am struggling to work out how to do it in reverse.

Comment: How do you query for locations in a given radius?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you running (because the available spatial analysis functions vary)? I suspect you're going to need to store a bounding box in the spatial table for the circle defined by the radius, then query to find all the candidate boxes containing your point, and then filter the results to exclude the points where the bounding box rectangle overshoots the radius near the outer corners.  It should still be possible for the optimizer to leverage the spatial index to do most of the work and then filter the rest.